# Extracting certain hex values from a string to a new string

Tags: c, bitmap, hex, bit-manipulation, bit

I have a string in Hex ASCII Format [3x3x3x3x] with variable x, x-(0...F).

For example I can get in data

`inData = 0x30303f3f` and want to convert it to:

`outData = 0x00ff`

or

`inData = 0x3f3f3f3f`

`outData = 0xffff`

How is the best way to do bit operations here, really I just want to skip the "3s"?

```
// receive answer from device
if (ReceiveMsg(FLog, TLog::INFO, FSerial, &ReceiveStr))
{
    int side;
    char inData[4];
    char serial[6];
    char status;

    if (sscanf(ReceiveStr.GetData(), "\x2%6s\x84%1d%4c%c", &serial, &side, &inData, &status) == 4) {

        *Status = status & 0x0f;

        // decode hex ASCII
        int time = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
            time = time + ((inData[i] & 0x0f) *(pow(16, j)));
            j++;
        }
        *Timer = time;
        result = true;
    }
}
```

- inData[4] = 0x30, 0x30, 0x3f, 0x3f
- time = 255 (output)

I wonder if there is any way to do what the for-loop does any faster, like with bit shifting or similar?

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: Is the output still a string or do you want to parse it as well? And do you allow things like as `_pext_u32` or `_mm_shuffle_epi8`?

Comment: That makes no sense. `0x30303f3f` is not `0x00ff`, and `0x3f3f3f3f` is not `0xffff`

Comment: you need one value not four.you can do 
`
union {
char w[4];
uint t;
} h;

Comment: in case of you dont know it "<<" is bitshift operator

Comment: and nobody  wanna to repeat  my answer.

Comment: AND if union member is used for output from sscanf order of bytes in it's uint would be different then expected.

Comment: Yes I know "<<" is bitshift operator, but unsure how to apply it to this problem :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
char inData[] = "0x30303f3f";
char outData[7] = "0x";
outData[2] = inData[3];
outData[3] = inData[5];
outData[4] = inData[7];
outData[5] = inData[9];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final_result=source<<4 & 0xf0000000+source<<8 & 0x0f000000+source<<12 & 0x00f00000+source<<16 & 0x000f0000 ;
final_result>>=16;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to binary data, for example data from a binary file, or data in memory. This data can be represented as string in hexadecimal format:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char data[] = { 0x30, 0x30, 0x3F, 0x3F };
    int data_size = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);

    char *str = malloc(data_size * 2 + 1);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < data_size; i++)
        sprintf(&str[i * 2], "%02X", data[i]);
    str[i * 2] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Result is `"30303F3F"`

Or the data can be stored in a string, but that's not very common.

```
int main()
{
    const char *data = "0123456789";
    int data_size = strlen(data);

    char *str = malloc(data_size * 2 + 1);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < data_size; i++)
        sprintf(&str[i * 2], "%02X", data[i]);
    str[i * 2] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Result: `"30313233343536373839"`

Note that `0` is a character whose value is `0x30`, and `1` is `0x31` etc. That's where all those 3's come from.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if there is any way to do what the for-loop does any faster…

You have the `char` array:

> - inData[4] = 0x30, 0x30, 0x3f, 0x3f

You want an `int`:

> - time = 255 (output)

Indeed you can *unroll* the loop

```
            time = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
            time = time + ((inData[i] & 0x0f) *(pow(16, j)));
            j++;
        }
```

to

```
        time = inData[0]-48<<12|inData[1]-48<<8|inData[2]-48<<4|inData[3]-48;
```

(at the same time using potentially less expensive shift operations rather than `pow`).